# How to unbind a previous jQuery hover / click event?

Tags: jquery

I want to unbind the mouseover event when the element is clicked.

HTML markup:

```
<div id="foto"></div>
<div id="flotante"></div>
<div id="flotante2"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#foto').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('#flotante').delay(2000).show('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('#flotante').hide('slow');
    },
    click: function(){
        // I want the mouseover event to stop executing.        
         $('#flotante2').show();
    }
});
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/K85DN/

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `$('#foto').off('mouseover')` inside the click callback ?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. The mouseover event still fires.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K85DN/1/ working well for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K85DN/2/

Answer (score 1):

Some changes

1. Use namespaced event handlers since we need to remove them.
2. Use setTimeout() to delay the display since we will have to cancel it if the mouse leaves the element before 2 seconds
3. Use .stop() to handle the animation queue

Try

```
var $flotante = $('#flotante');
$('#foto').on({
    'mouseover.display': function () {
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $flotante.stop(true, true).show('slow');
        }, 2000)
        $flotante.data('timer', timer);
    },
    'mouseleave.display': function () {
        clearTimeout($flotante.data('timer'))
        $flotante.stop(true, true).hide('slow');
    },
    click: function () {
        $(this).off('mouseover.display mouseleave.display');
        clearTimeout($flotante.data('timer'));
        $flotante.stop(true, true).hide('slow');
        $('#flotante2').show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/naeEK/)

Comment: @RaulEscarcega it is fixed now... try the demo again